# extract lines according to a particular column

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, grep

I have a CSV file like

```
CK,ck
XYZ,xyz,xyzs
ABC,abc,abcs
PQR,pqr,pqrs
LMN,lmn,
IJK,ijk,
```

I have to check if something is written in column 3 except whitespace, then display the whole line.the output will be:

```
XYZ,xyz,xyzs
ABC,abc,abcs
PQR,pqr,pqrs
```

Answer (score 7):

A `sed` approach:

```
sed -n '/[^,]*,[^,]*,[^, ]\+/p' file
```

Or a `grep` solution:

```
grep -oE '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^, ]+' file
```

And `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /[^, ]+/' file
```

Comment: Good one chaos, nice and clean.

Comment: you need to add a start of line anchor to your `grep` regex. Also, `-E` should suffice, no need for `-P`

Comment: @1_CR edited the answer

Comment: Love the awk example, had to lookup how it was evaluated and learned something today, thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that `'$3 ~ /[^ ]/'` is good enough (for the `awk` solution). If the field separator is `,`, you don't need to check for comma(s) in field values, and if all you're looking for is one non-blank character, you don't need the `+`. Then again, since the question says "something ... except whitespace", you should have `'$3 ~ /[^ \t]/'`.

Comment: `$3 ~ /[^[:blank:]]/` might be even better

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, '$3 && $3 != " "' file
XYZ,xyz,xyzs
ABC,abc,abcs
PQR,pqr,pqrs
```

or:

```
$ awk -F, '$3 ~ /[^[:blank:]]/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this in awk :

```
awk -F',' '{gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$3)}$3' foo.csv
```

This will remove trailing whitespaces and only print if there's something left in the third field.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3' input_file
```